# using Ajax to call a database - having trouble passing the input on click

Tags: ajax

I am a total noob at this ajax stuff, but I was wondering how one would go about doing something like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

but with the event happening on the click of a button.  here is a copy of the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHint(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
{
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
 }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form>
 First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" size="20" />
 </form>
 <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I've attempted to add an input button with an onclick, but I can't get it to pass the value of the input text box.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the input field and access the value with document.getElementById('TEXTBOXID').value